# Redirecting home page to a subdomain, but keeping root domain for blog and ecommerce

Tags: redirects, ecommerce

This is a fairly unique situation, hence my question here.

My client has an ecommerce business that includes both retail and wholesale customers. We recently changed her retail side over to Shopify and that site is at shop.example.com. The wholesale site remains at example.com. There's also a blog there.

We are redirecting only the home page of example.com to shop.example.com for logged-out users. Visitors to the blog posts and wholesale customers (when logged in) can still access urls under example.com, like 'example.com/blog-post/.

What are the SEO implications for this? Do I need to change any settings in Search Console?

Comment: So you can't read the blog or see the wholesale site unless you are logged in?

Comment: No, as I said, blog visitors and logged in wholesale customers still see everything except the home page.

Comment: How does somebody login to the wholesale site?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller There is an example.com/wholesale/ page for login.